# Blocking a subdomain of a website from being indexed

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, blocking

how can i prevent a subdomain to not show up in search results.  like it.domain.com

Is there an htaccess file??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a [`robots.txt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) into its root directory and have it say

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

decent spiders (i.e. all big search engines) will respect it.

Comment: @AAA no, `/` will remove all pages. You are aware that pages will still be accessible by the outside world if they manage to guess or find the URL elsewhere, right? They will just not show up in search engines this way.

Comment: Yup.. sorry thats what i meant.  its ok if they find it like that but don't want it in search engines.  thanks Pekka.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but Try this::

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

**NOTE** :this code is already submitted